# Rails simple_form gives dots under stars for required fields, better way to remove them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, required

In many of my projects I use simple_form and love it.
However one really strange quirk that I find is that I get 3 small dots underneath the * it supplies for required fields.

I have to get around it with:

```
= f.input :name, :label => '*', :required => false # Display purpose only (it is required)
```

Which is messy because the field is required, so this code looks ugly.

Is there a better fix for what seems like a common problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it's from CSS, if you are useing blueprint, "`abbr` and `accronym`" tags have a `border-bottom: 1px dotted black` style.

Try add to your css file the next line :

```
abbr, accronym{ border-bottom: 0px; } /*try adding !important  after 0px if doesn't work*/
```

Wish helps :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like CSS stuff. See what are the properties for abbr tags on your CSS.

Comment: I doubt it as I have seen this on multiple projects and pc's.

Comment: I never see this behavior before. Could you provide a code example?

Comment: The code is just that it uses simple_form and the line above.  However I also see this in apps that even other people in other orgs create so I do not believe it is specific to my code and looking at my code will be a distraction.  I appreciate best guesses but in this example I'm hoping that someone else who has actually experienced this will be able to shed some light for us.

Comment: I create one application from scratch with rails 3.0 and simple_form and I don't see any dots under the *. What browser are you using?

Comment: Multiple browser, multiple platforms. code is
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/gorilla_groups" class="simple_form gorilla_group" id="new_gorilla_group" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="1KUd9OIZx/mEhBSz++8AAfIyoj3Mfqiklr4GNAQVCv8=" /></div>
<div class='field'>

Comment: <div class="input string required"><label class="string required" for="gorilla_group_name"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Name: </label><input class="string required" id="gorilla_group_name" name="gorilla_group[name]" size="50" type="text" /></div>
</div>
<div class='actions'>
<input id="gorilla_group_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Save" />
</div>
</form>

Comment: I didn't see anything strange on this HTML. You are the first person that report something like this. I never see theses three dots under the *

Comment: I have voted to close this (my own q) as others don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple form adds an abbr with a border-bottom.
You can remove the border-bottom just with css, but you also need to override the text underline property (which I think comes from default navigator styles)

So, this small css block should work :

```
  form abbr[title] {
    border-bottom: none !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
  }
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct, leaving some explanation would improve this question in a long run.

Answer (score 0):

There's another solution that I found, in case anyone else comes across this question in the future. I responded to a [similar issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/1653) that was closed on simple_form with this:

> I had this issue too, and it would be pretty easy for the simple_form
>   maintainers to change, so it might be worth looking into. At the very
>   least, I'd like to help if someone else runs into the problem using
>   the gem combination I'm using. On a new rails 5.2.3 app, with
>   bootstrap 4.3.1 and simple form 4.1.0, I had the same issue with an
>   ellipses under the asterisk.
>
> I found a way to solve it, since it actually only happens when using
>   the tag. In locales/simple_form.en.yml, if you remove mark: '*', and
>   change html: '*' to html: '*', this removes the ".." that appears under
>   the asterisk. This occurs because there's an included style with
>   bootstrap that adds an underlined dotted border to any abbreviation
>   tags, which allow the user to select that text in order to view the
>   rest of the word.